# коллекция перебирается через foreach

Tags: javascript

foreach есть только у элемента массива почему с его помощью можно перебрать коллекцию ?

```js
document.body.childNodes.forEach(elem => {
    console.log(elem);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <a name="list">the list</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
    <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
    <li><a href="ftp://ftp.com/my.zip">ftp://ftp.com/my.zip</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://internal.com/test">http://internal.com/test</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
<script src="common.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: _foreach есть только у элемента массива_ - это неверное утверждение

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Можете создать объект, в нем создать метод forEach и пользоваться. Просто так получилось, что, у массивов, метода forEach наболее известен и больше "на слуху"

Comment: я правильно понял у что у коллекции NodeList также есть метод forEach ?

Comment: вы правильно поняли

Comment: спасибо за внимание

Comment: forEach будет работать с любым итерируемым объектом. Кроме массивов и коллекций это еще и Map, например. Кроме того, вы можете добавить итератор в произвольный объект и на нём тоже будет работать forEach (а так же другие способы воспользоваться итератором, вроде for of)